# Postgres: Insert values in two tables simultaneously from csv

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with each a foreign key referencing the other:

```
users
favorite_post_id int NOT NULL
```

```
posts
user_id int NOT NULL
```

Consider a user can have many posts, but only a single favorite post.

I want to seed my database with two CSV files using the `COPY` command. The data contain rows that reference each other (i.e. a post with `(id: 2, user_id: 1)`, and a user with `(id: 1, favorite_post_id: 2)`)

However I'm unable to get the insertion to happen simultaneously, resulting in an error of inserting to one table violating the foreign constraint to the other.

```
insert or update on table "posts" violates foreign key constraint "FK_d8feca7198a0931f8234dcc58d7"

Key (user_id)=(1) is not present in table "users".
```

Is there a way to commit the insertion at once, so that it happens simultaneously?

Comment: Disable the foreign constraints and re-enable them after you have loaded both tabes.

Comment: If the user table uniquely identifies each user, then this design will allow only a single post per user.  Is that your intent?  A design that allows multiple posts per user would have a FK from posts into users, but not vice-versa--and would not create such foreign key errors when loading data.

Comment: @rd_nielsen True, a bit of a poor example. Consider a user can only have one favorite_post_id, but many posts.

Comment: If a user has no favorite post, then presumably `users.post_id` is nullable.  In that case, load the data without setting `users.post_id` and then update `users` to set `post_id` after the `posts` table is loaded.

Comment: @rd_nielsen That would make sense, but `favorite_post_id` is not nullable in the actual scenario. Consider the user has to mark a favorite post upon registering. A bit silly, I should definitely consider a better example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are certain that the imports won't cause inconsistencies, you can

```
BEGIN;

SET LOCAL session_replication_role = replica;

COPY users FROM ...;
COPY posts FROM ...;

COMMIT;
```

This setting will disable triggers and hence foreign key constraints.

If you are not 100% certain of the data, the better way is to drop one of the foreign key constraints, load the tables and create the constraint again.

You can do that in a transaction as well if you need to prevent concurrent activity from creating inconsistencies.

Comment: I also needed to reset session_replication_role to default after committing: `SET session_replication_role = origin;`

Comment: Yes. Or you use `SET LOCAL` as in my updated answer.